# Shell Scripting using sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Sample script is shown below:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i~ 's/user1/user2/g' myfile.txt
```

It replaces user1 with user2 in myfile.txt

How can I change above script to get confirmation that the script found user1 & replaced it with user2?

Basically, if it doesn't find user1, it should give an alert message on the command prompt.

Thanks!

Comment: You could have `sed` touch a flag file if it does a successful substitution. As an optimization, only do it for the first match. If your input files are too large for the grep && sed and diff solutions, it might be worth piecing together a somewhat more complex sed script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to diffing after is to grep before:

```
grep -q 'user1' myfile.txt && sed -i~ 's/user1/user2/g' myfile.txt || echo "user1 not there"
```

The `-q` means that grep runs quietly and returns success if found, so then and only then will it go on to do the replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Try `diff` tool:

```
fgrep -q 'user1'  myfile.txt 2>&1 1>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
   echo " user1 found."
fi
...
diff -q myfile.txt myfile.txt~ 2>&1 1>/dev/null
if [ "$?" -eq 1 ]; then
   echo " Match found & Replaced."
fi
```

Comment: I've 5 sed commands in my script & I really want to check each of those string being replaced or not. How can I do that?

Comment: @Mike, you can split the `sed` operations into distinct commands and do what John says after each one.